# UIWebView iPhone OS 4.0 can't view YouTube video

Tags: video, uiwebview, youtube, ios4

I used to have a UIWebView that links to our web page. This page contains a list of YouTube videos and when each video is played when a user selects on it.

This app works well in iPhone OS 3.0, but it doesn't work on iPhone OS 4.0 anymore.

I tried loading my web page on iPhone Safari, it doesn't work either. 
I tried this URL http://m.youtube.com  on the iPhone Safari, all the videos can't be played.
Is it a bug on iPhone OS 4.0? can I use UIWebView on 4.0 SDK?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer, my iPhone was jail broken and I deleted the YouTube icon from the home screen.
When I reset the device back to factory settings, and re-jailbreak it again. Everything works fine.

Still don't know the exact reason, but I assume that UIWebViewController uses some library from YouTube app folder.